# Programmatically retrieve the MySite URL of user

Tags: user-profile, my-site, object-model

Let's say that we have the SPUser object of current user - how do I programmatically retrieve his mysite URL path, for example "mydomain:8080/personal/saltarski"?

Currently I do it through string manipulation:

```
var loginName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.Substring(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
var hostName = SPContext.Current.Site.HostName;
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://" + hostName + ":8080/personal/" + loginName + "/")
```

This works for most cases, however I find that it breaks for some users like the System Admin, when his loginName resolves to 'system' but the actual path to the mysite contains his actual credentials' login name.

Is there a more elegant solution to what I am doing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[UserProfile.PersonalSite property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.personalsite.aspx)  gets the personal site of the User:

```
var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(ServerContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site));
var profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\\username");
using (SPSite personalSite = profile.PersonalSite)
{
     var personalSiteUrl = personalSite.PersonalUrl; 
}
```

Comment: nice one and its working for me .

Comment: Nice one to read about my site property

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(userProfile.PersonalSite.ID, this.Site.Zone))
{
   string redirectURL = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(site.Url, SourceUrl);
   CommonHelper.RedirectToPage(redirectURL, false, false, this.Context);
}
```

Do not forget about Zone!